# Multiple exclude rules with YUI Compressor for .NET and MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, yui

I am looking how to exclude multiple files with a wildcard match in MSBuild settings XML for YUI Compressor for .NET

Currently I have this:

```
Exclude="$(ProjectDir)../../Scripts/plugins/*.min.js"
```

But also want to exclude files that match:

```
*-vsdoc.js
```

How should this extra wild card pattern be added to the Exclude attribute?

The full XML currently looks like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
  ...
  <JavaScriptFiles Include="$(ProjectDir)../../Scripts/plugins/*.js" Exclude="$(ProjectDir)../../Scripts/plugins/*.min.js" />
  ...
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution... So I'll answer this one myself.

To have multiple exclude rules you use '**;**' as a delimiter.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <JavaScriptFiles 
     Include="$(ProjectDir)../../Scripts/plugins/*.js" 
     Exclude="$(ProjectDir)../../Scripts/plugins/*.min.js;
              $(ProjectDir)../../Scripts/plugins/*-vsdoc.js" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this by gradually excluding items:

```
  <ItemGroup>
      <JavaScriptContent Include="$(ProjectDir)\..\..\Scripts\**\*.js"/>
      <JavaScriptContent Exclude="$(ProjectDir)\..\..\Scripts\plugins\*.min.js" />
      <JavaScriptContent Exclude="$(ProjectDir)\**\*-vsdoc.js" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: I tried adding the exclude on to multiple lines but that didn't work. I got a build error "The attribute 'Exclude' in element <JavaScriptFiles> is unrecognized." I've edited my question to show a more detailed code snippet.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. From [the docs for MSBuild Items](//msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171453.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Anchor_4): "The Exclude attribute affects only the items that are added by the Include attribute in the item element that contains them both."